# Convert PNG to XNB without XNA Studio

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm using MonoGame in Windows Phone 8 game development. As you know MonoGame has no built-in content processing like XNA Studio and now I can't install XNA anymore (it required VS 2010 - my version is 2013).

So how can I convert a PNG image to XNB file without XNA Studio installed?

Answer (score 2):

You might not need to:

According to this answer: [C# MonoGame Help? (Content.Load<Texture2D>("Invader");)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953880/c-sharp-monogame-help-content-loadtexture2dinvader) `.PNG` is a supported texture format meaning you should be able to use the usual `Content.Load<Texture2D>("PngFileNameWithoutExtension");` providing it's in your content folder.

When it can't find the xnb file it'll look for other supported formats, png being one of them.

Comment: Thank you, It may haven't supported on Windows Phone 8 yet... I got a NotImplementYet exception

Comment: In that case you might have to install XNA game studio just so you can compile the content files. You should be able to install it along side your VS2013 installation.

Comment: I found this: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230. It seem I have to install this version of XNA Game Studio

Answer (score 0):

Here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xnbbuilder/

Allows you to convert a bunch of file types to XNB format.

Comment: Note: The full version of XNA game studio is required for this.

Comment: Ah... I never used it, I just remembered seeing it.